# create buffer source in ffmpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am trying to create an AVFilter buffer for video.

my source code is

```
     AVFilterContext *buffersrc_ctx= nullptr;
     AVFilterContext *buffersink_ctx = nullptr;
     const AVFilter *buffersrc  = avfilter_get_by_name("buffer");
     const AVFilter *buffersink = avfilter_get_by_name("buffersink");
     AVFilterInOut *outputs = avfilter_inout_alloc();
     AVFilterInOut *inputs  = avfilter_inout_alloc();
     data->graph = avfilter_graph_alloc();

 snprintf(args, sizeof(args),
             "video_size=%dx%d:pix_fmt=%d:time_base=%d/%d:pixel_aspect=%d/%d",
             data->codec_ctx->width,  data->codec_ctx->height,  data->codec_ctx->pix_fmt,
             data->codec_ctx->time_base.num, data->codec_ctx->time_base.den,
             data->codec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.num, data->codec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.den);

    ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersrc_ctx, buffersrc, "in",
                                       args, NULL, filter_graph);
    if (ret < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot create buffer source\n");
        goto end;
    }
```

I got following error

> [in @ 0x1cdd9c0] Invalid parameters provided. Cannot create a buffer
>   source

also deinfed avfilter_register_all(); in begin of source code. 
Any ideas why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

I add the following lines of code in where open video frames. follow this link for the solution.
https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.7/filtering_video_8c-example.html

```
    /* select the video stream */
    ret = av_find_best_stream(fmt_ctx, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, -1, -1, &dec, 0);
    if (ret < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot find a video stream in the input file\n");
        return ret;
    }
    video_stream_index = ret;
    dec_ctx = fmt_ctx->streams[video_stream_index]->codec;
    av_opt_set_int(dec_ctx, "refcounted_frames", 1, 0);
```